# Adjust the font size of axis ticks and axis labels in 3D surface plot using Plotly

Tags: python, plotly

How to set the font size of axis ticks and axis labels of a 3D surface plot created using Plotly. Also, how to adjust the spacing between the axis ticks and axis label?

**Edit**

I am able to set the font size of axis ticks and axis labels using the following:

```
fig.update_scenes(xaxis = dict(title='X-axis title',tickfont=dict(size=12),titlefont=dict(size=14)))
```

I am not able to adjust the spacing between the axis label and axis ticks.

Comment: [This](https://plotly.com/python/axes/) covers your question. you'd need to apply it to the 3d axis you want to work with.